# How to REPLACE INTO using MERGE INTO for upsert in Delta Lake?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, upsert, delta-lake

The recommended way of doing an upsert in a delta table is the following.

```
MERGE INTO users
USING updates
ON users.userId = updates.userId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET address = updates.addresses
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (userId, address) VALUES (updates.userId, updates.address)
```

Here `updates` is a table. My question is how can we do an upsert directly, that is, without using a source table. I would like to give the values myself directly.

In *SQLite*, we could simply do the following.

```
REPLACE INTO table(column_list)
VALUES(value_list);
```

Is there a simple way to do that for Delta tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A source table can be a subquery so the following should give you what you're after.

```
MERGE INTO events
USING (VALUES(...)) // round brackets are required to denote a subquery
ON false            // an artificial merge condition
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
```